# Extract dynamic content with iMacros

Tags: imacros

I'm entirely new to iMacros, and I'm trying to get iMacros to extract the email address that appears when you click "reply" on ads like [these](https://losangeles.craigslist.org/lac/res/d/looking-for-any-job/7028936000.html). (Link is "dead"...)

The only thing I have is:

```
VERSION BUILD=10021450

URL GOTO=https://losangeles.craigslist.org/sfv/res/d/need-extra-money/7027377618.html

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:reply
```

I have tried simply using wildcards, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer somehow:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=CLASS:anonemail EXTRACT=TXT
```